# Symbolic polynomial interpolation

Tags: polynomials, symbolic-computation

I'm trying to create polynomials from some symbolic points to discretize derivations. This means I'm having data like
$(a, \phi(a)),\  (b, \phi(b) ) $and $(c, \phi(c))$ and want to fit a second order polynomial through these points.

I tried Matlabs polyfit but it can't handle syms. I also had a look at Maxima, but couldn't find any function there neither.

I'd be really happy if someone could point out how to do this in a CAS.

Comment: For three points, why not do it by hand symbolically? The Lagrange interpolation isn't hard for that.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I need to to it for higher orders as well, so by hand gets really frustrating.

Comment: Ah, yes, for more points, it quickly becomes cumbersome by hand. You might have some success checking the docs for "Lagrange" or "interpolation".

Comment: What are your points?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica can find an interpolating polynomial symbolically. For example,

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{a, w}, {b, x}, {c, y}, {d, z}}, t]
```

yields this answer:

$$(t-a) \left((t-b) \left(\frac{(t-c) \left(\frac{\frac{z-y}{d-c}-\frac{y-x}{c-b}}{d-b}-\frac{\frac{y-x}{c-b}-\frac{x-w}{b-a}}{c-a}\right)}{d-a}+\frac{\frac{y-x}{c-b}-\frac{x-w}{b-a}}{c-a}\right)+\frac{x-w}{b-a}\right)+w.$$

Answer (score 0):

It annoys me when Matlab functions aren't overloaded for symbolic calculation. Looking at the code for [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) (`edit polyfit` in the command window) it seems that doing what you need may be quite easy. I comes down to constructing a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and solving a least squares problem. The existing code can be adapted for symbolic math.

In fact, I couldn't resist and gave it try. You can find my code for `polyfitsym.` [on my GitHub](https://github.com/horchler/polyfitsym).

For an example, in your three point, second-order polynomial case, let $\phi(x) = \sin(x)$. First we'll solve for three arbitrary symbolic points $x_1 = a$, $x_2 = b$, and $x_3 = c$. Later we'll explicitly set $a = -3$, $b = -1$, and $c = 1$.

```
x = sym('x',[3 1]);   % Vector of three symbolic data points
y = sin(x);           % phi(x), apply function to vector, see help for other forms
p = polyfitsym(x,y,2) % Return coefficients for second order polynomial
```

which returns the symbolic result

```
p =

[ -(x1*sin(x2)-x2*sin(x1)-x1*sin(x3)+x3*sin(x1)+x2*sin(x3)-x3*sin(x2))/((x1-x2)*(x1*x2-x1*x3-x2*x3+x3^2)), ...
   (x1^2*sin(x2)-x2^2*sin(x1)-x1^2*sin(x3)+x3^2*sin(x1)+x2^2*sin(x3)-x3^2*sin(x2))/((x1-x2)*(x1*x2-x1*x3-x2*x3+x3^2)), ...
  -(x1*x2^2*sin(x3)-x1*x3^2*sin(x2)+x2*x3^2*sin(x1)-x1^2*x2*sin(x3)+x1^2*x3*sin(x2)-x2^2*x3*sin(x1))/((x1-x2)*(x1*x2-x1*x3-x2*x3+x3^2)) ]
```

This can be simplified a bit with [`simple`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simple.html) or [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) or you can plug in numeric values with [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html):

```
abc = [-3;-1;1];        % Three numeric data points
p2 = subs(p,x,sym(abc)) % Cast points to symbolic to keeps coefficients symbolic
```

which gives (still symbolic – use `double` to convert to floating point if you like)

```
p2 =

[ (3*sin(1))/8 - sin(3)/8, sin(1), sin(3)/8 - (3*sin(1))/8]
```

You might wish to plot this and see how good the fit is over a range:

```
x2 = -2*pi:0.2:2*pi;
f = polyval(double(p2),x2);  % polyval also only supports floating point
plot(x2,sin(x2),'o',x2,f,'-',abc,sin(abc),'*');
axis([x2(1) x2(end)  -2  2]);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y(x)'); legend('sin(x)','fit','data'); legend boxoff;
```

which results in a figure like this:
[image]

There is another example in the help for the function. Since I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, the `polyfitsym` function is pretty general and works very much like `polyfit`. Feel free to modify, improve, and use it as you need. I can't guarantee that it won't have numeric issues (for some test cases all of the coefficients were `Inf` for some reason) or that it will be able to handle everything. It uses [`sym/linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/linsolve.html) rather that `\` ([`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)) to solve the least squares linear system because it returns warnings if the the problem is ill-conditioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great example!

Comment: @Paul: Did this or another answer help you with your problem? Consider accepting an answer if so.